# How to hook into adding watchdog entries by other modules?

Tags: 7, security, log-messages

Is it possible to write some code to intercept the process of adding Watchdog entries and filter them before adding to the log? Or is there a module that allows for watchdog filtering before adding to log? (I searched but nothing found) This would be useful if there are tons of well-known messages (like page not found from the same referrer or the same IP) that obfuscate the log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately `hook_watchdog` doesn't provide a return value which could block the insertion of the log entry in the database.

Note though that the responsible module for inserting the entry in the database is `dblog`. You could disable that and write your own implementation of it, although you'd have to replicate lots of functionality.

Another idea is to have a frequent cron job deleting the relevant log entries from the database table.

Comment: You mean the cron job as configured in Linux or in Drupal? If in Drupal, then how to specify what are the "Relevant log entries" ? I have a couple of regular expressions, where to put them?

Comment: I mean the cron mechanism of Drupal. Regarding the "relevant log entries" I meant the log entries which you consider that are worth deletion. I don't know which these are, you do. The implementation of `dblog` contains a cron function from which you could get some ideas.

Comment: From looking at the dblog_cron function, I'll try to write a custom function that does db_delete('watchdog') with  conditions containing regular expressions that specify what to delete  -and it should do it

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's still relevant, but I've made a module where you can control logging per type per level: http://drupal.org/project/watchdog_filtering

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a module that adds the needed D7 hook:

https://www.drupal.org/project/watchdogalter

> This module adds a hook_watchdog_alter. Used in DBLog Booster.

https://www.drupal.org/project/dblogbooster